# Memory usage and stability of Kafka vs ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, activemq-artemis

We have been using ActiveMQ (Artemis) quite well for few years. Recently, we thought of exploring Kafka instead of ActiveMQ for better throughput. Our experience was mixed. We are running both the applications in Linux machines.

1. Compared to ActiveMQ, we understood that Kafka requires more infrastructure (dedicated virtual machines) whereas ActiveMQ could run along with other applications in a box. Kafka was crashing abruptly after a few days if we try to run it along with other applications. Why is this happening?
2. Kafka require much more memory than ActiveMQ. Several times after the crash, we found that it is due to OutofMemoryError in Kafka (whereas ActiveMQ was running very fine in the same machine)
3. Our production servers were running ActiveMQ in single node whereas if for Kafka, clustering is required.
4. Kafka has no built in UI. Yes, we can get other tools like Kafdrop.
5. Kafka require one Zookeeper node / cluster as well.

Overall, we found that Kafka require costly infrastructure and monitoring tools. But I know that Kafka is being used by many great companies.

I would like to know why Kafka is crashing often with memory error. Is there something wrong with our setup? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: As it is currently written this question is way too vague. If I were you I'd simply focus on the specifics of the Kafka issue you're observing. Comparing Kafka to ActiveMQ Artemis like this doesn't serve to solve your problem, and frankly doesn't make a lot of sense in general. They differ drastically in their implementations and in many cases are deployed to solve very different problems. I would not expect them to necessarily have the same kind of runtime characteristics.

Comment: It's not clear how much memory you **did** give. The documentation recommends 6GB on dedicated machines for production environments (and 3-5 dedicated Zookeeper servers, not one)

Comment: It's also worth noting that you may not be able to gain any additional throughput for your use-case with Kafka as compared to ActiveMQ Artemis. Every use-case is different, of course, but [this benchmark](https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/) involving persistence and replication demonstrated throughput results that were very close between the two.

Comment: Thanks Justin. We wanted a message broker to communicate between various microservices. As you said, they have different implementations. My use case is simple, so my question is: which is light on resources for a stable setup - ActiveMQ or Kafka? To me, apparently the answer seems to be the former.

Comment: To be clear, the microservices communicate via an asynchronous channel.